# Python - Dictionary of sets with the same key

Tags: python, dictionary, set, key

I'm trying to create a function that will read a text file that has one word on each line, like

> afd
>   asmv
>   adsasd

It will take words of the user given length and will construct a python dictionary where the key is a string of the word where the letters are sorted.  The values will be a set of all words that have the same key.  So far I have:

```py
def setdict():
wordfile = argv[1]
open(wordfile, "r")
setdict = {}
for line in wordfile:
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        word = word.rstrip("\n")
        if word == wordlength:
            key = str(sorted(word))
```

I'm a little lost on how to create the sets with words that have the same key and put them in the dictionary.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For future reference, in computing terms, the general concept you're looking for is a "multi-dict" (or "multi-map" or "multi-mapping", etc.)—like a dict (or map, etc.), but with multiple values per key. This is one of those cases where knowing the right word makes it easy to search for answers, but without that word it's nearly impossible. (You'd find that iIn Python, a multi-dict is usually represented as a `dict` whose values are either `set`s or `list`s of the real values, and it's usually built with `collections.defaultdict` or the `setdefault` method on `dict`, as in Robᵩ's answer.)

Answer (score 1):

`collections.defaultdict` is useful here:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint


words = defaultdict(set)

with open('input.txt') as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        for word in line.split():
            sorted_list = sorted(word)
            sorted_str = ''.join(sorted_list)
            words[sorted_str].add(word)

pprint(words)
```

Of course, anything you can do with `defaultdict`, you can also do with `dict.setdefault()`:

```
words = dict()
with open('input.txt') as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        for word in line.split():
            sorted_list = sorted(word)
            sorted_str = ''.join(sorted_list)
            words.setdefault(sorted_str, set()).add(word)
```

Comment: +1. Using `defaultdict` is definitely better than either testing `in` or using `try`/`except`. And when `defaultdict` isn't appropriate (e.g., because you need an actual `dict`, that will raise `KeyError`s), `words.setdefault` is still better than the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

start with something simple

```
words = ["hello","python","world"]
my_dict = {}
for word in words:
    try:
       my_dict[sorted(word)].append(word)
    except KeyError:
       my_dict[sorted(word)] = [word]
```

now instead of using predefined words read them from a file

```
  words = map(str.split,open("some_word_file.txt"))
```

Answer (score 0):

the key here is to access the dictionary with a for loop that makes the value set available for manipulation. you can solve your problem by reading the file linewise (readline) and checking the following:

```
for key, value in my_dict:
    if sorted(word) == key:
        value.append(word)
    else:
        my_dict[sorted(word)] = value
```